# Weird blurred SKShapeNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skshapenode

I am trying to start with the basics of SpriteKit and draw a rounded rectangle

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit


class UINode: SKShapeNode {

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: -5, y: -2, width: 10, height: 4), cornerRadius: 1).cgPath
        self.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        self.fillColor = UIColor.red 
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

The respective Scene containing that SKShapeNode contains a SKCameraNode, which can be moved and scaled for panning/zooming. That works fine.

However the output of that Shape is very strange, as you can see in the attachment. This is the result of the above code.
I have no idea what's going on. If I reduce the cornerRadius to zero, I get a rectangular shape with the same strange white border and artifacts. But I except a simple rounded Rect without any blurring, second color or artifacts (thin lines)

What am I doing wrong?
[Rendering result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Uf0t.png)

[image]

Comment: If you don't want the border, change the `strokeColor` from the default white to clear. Not sure about the artifacts. You might try just the `init(rectOf: cornerRadius:)` initializer instead of going through a CGPath.

Comment: Have you tried creating the UIBezierPath with positive value ? `CGRect(x: 5, y: 2, width: 10, height: 4)`

Comment: The problem might relate to the fact that my SKScene is implemented inside a SwiftUI view. I don't have the blurring issue when I create a new SpriteKit-only iOS game project.

Comment: Did you solve your problem eventually? I am currently facing the same issue...